# Make more visible icons on request

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, sobject, icon

[image]

Is it possibile to make the icon and the pen in the layout more visible?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: For what it's worth, the pencil (edit) icon does become darker when you hover over the field. Having a visual distinction between interaction states is generally considered good UX design, I believe.